# Having trouble with mule append-string-transfomer

Tags: mule

I am using this configuration expression.

```
<flow name="quartz">
  <quartz:inbound-endpoint name="quartzstart" jobName="job1" repeatInterval="5000">
  <quartz:envent=generator-job/>
  <byte-array-to-string-transformer/>
  <append-string-transformer message="Check Message"/>
  <tcp:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="7778" connector-ref="protocol"/>
</flow>
```

It triggers every 5 seconds.

I was expecting the received message to be

> Check Message

but the message I received was

> (NullPayload)Check Message

How can I receive only "Check Message" ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the toString of a null payload is returning (NullPayload).

You could set-payload with an empty string before the appender, or if this is your full logic just set-payload with "Check Message".